# apache question mark RewriteRule question

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, regex

So i am trying to redirect from

```
index.php?action=search&query=search text goes here
```

to

```
search?query=search text goes here
```

i tried this so far but with no luck

```
RewriteRule ^search/? index.php?action=search&query=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**EDIT :** Solution was

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^query=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^search/? index.php?action=search&query=%1 [QSA,L]
```

and since i had some other RewriteRules in my htaccess i had to put them above them.

my other rewriterules were like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?action=$1
```

Comment: You mean the other way around? From `search...` to `index.php?...`?

Comment: from index to search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^query=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^search/? index.php?action=search&query=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: it still does show up the $_GET["query"]

Comment: ok this seems to work but my other rewrotes affected it... thanks

Comment: Are you able to get it working? Or you still having issues? If you still having issues please share your all rewrite rules.

Comment: i placed it on top and before my other rewriterules so its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture it into a capturing group.

```
RewriteRule ^search\?query=(.*)$ index.php?action=search&query=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: i am trying to retrieve the $_GET["query"] but it doesnt seem to show up... so it seems its not working